# What exactly is happening if I turn Dolby Atmos to 'Always On' on an iPhone 6s with AirPods Max?

Tags: iphone, audio, apple-music

Dolby Atmos is not officially supported on this iPhone, so there is no difference in sound between 'Automatic' and 'Off'. However, there is definitely an audible difference between 'Always On' and 'Automatic' (the volume is lower for one).

What exactly is happening when I set it to 'Always On'? Am I getting the full experience or not?

Comment: According to Apple, enable "sound check" and their volumes should become the same.